# Вывод массива в twig

Tags: массивы, twig, php, symfony2

Вывожу массив:

```
$data= array('text' => 'first', 'text2' => 'second');
return $this->render('SomeBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('data' => $data));
```

Шаблон:

```
{% for qdata in data %}
{{ qdata.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Ошибка:

> Impossible to access an attribute
> ("text") on a string variable
> ("first") in
> SomeBundle:Default:index.html.twig at
> line 2

При том следующий шаблон

```
{% for qdata in data %}
{{ data.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Выводит

> second

В чём проблема?

Comment: В массиве одинаковые ключи. :) Так же нельзя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да обычный foreach, чего там:

```
{% for value in data %}
    {# 'first' #}
    {# 'data' #}
//
{% for key, value in data %}
    {# 'text', 'first' #}
    {# 'text2', 'second' #}
```

**Обновление**

[[@sargss](/users/20610/sargss)](/users/20610/sargss), ну логика (именно логика) ничем не отличается:

```
{{ data['text'] }} {# выведет `first` #}

{% for key, value in data %}
    {% if key == 'text' or key == 'supertext' %} {# выводим только два конкретных элемента, и то, если они существуют #}
        {{ value }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Но что если мне ситуативно нужно вывести не все значения массива, а только некоторые?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for qdata in data %}
{{ data.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Это означает: вывести на экран значение {{ data.text }} столько раз, сколько элементов в массиве data

НО тут ошибка

```
{% for qdata in data %}
{{ qdata.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

потому что qdata - это не элемент массива data, а значение каждого элемента массива. Поэтому правильно будет так:

```
{% for qdata in data %}
-{{ qdata }}-
{% endfor %}
```

Выведет: "-first--second-" (Черточки поставил, чтобы отделить значение)